# multiple amount of args

Tags: python, arguments

I have a text document with serial numbers and I want to create a program where you run a function that tells you how many times a certain serial number occurs in the text document. I want the parameters to be unlimited in the sense that I could ask for 3 different serial numbers or just 1.

```
list of serial numbers:
pmos_4e
nmos_4e
pmos_4t
pmos_4f
nmos_4t
nmos_4f
pmos_4e
nmos_4e
pmos_4t
pmos_4f
nmos_4t
nmos_4f
pmos_4e
nmos_4e
pmos_4t
pmos_4f
nmos_4t
nmos_4f
pmos_4e
nmos_4e
pmos_4t
pmos_4f
nmos_4t
nmos_4f
pmos_4e
nmos_4e
pmos_4e
nmos_4e
pmos_4t
pmos_4f
nmos_4t
nmos_4f
pmos_4t
pmos_4f
nmos_4t
nmos_4f

current code:
def find_serial(*serial):

    f = open('C:/Users/joann/Desktop/pmos.txt', 'r')
    for z in range(len(serial)):


        x = 0
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i in lines:
            if (serial[z-1] in i):
                x += 1
        print(x)


    f.close()
```

When I run it I get the amount of times the first value shows up but it shows the rest as 0.

```
>>> find_serial('pmos_4e', 'nmos_4e', 'pmos_4t', 'pmos_4f')
6
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution_Update**

```
filename = "serials.txt"

def find_serial(*serial):

    serial_1, serial_2, serial_3, serial_4 = serial
    serials = [serial_1, serial_2, serial_3, serial_4]
    f = open('serials.txt', 'r')
    contents = f.read().split()

    for i in serials:
        x = 0
        for j in contents:
            if i == j:
                x +=1
        print(f"{i} count: {x}")

find_serial('pmos_4e', 'nmos_4e', 'pmos_4t', 'pmos_4f')
```

Same solution but I noticed you wanted to pass all the arguments at once to the function so I rewrote it so you could execute the `find_serial` function the original way you intended!

**Solution_Original**

```
filename = "serials.txt"

def find_serial(serial):
    f = open('serials.txt', 'r')
    contents = f.read().split()   
    x = 0
    for i in contents:
        if i == serial:
            x +=1
    print(f"{serial} count: {x}")

serials = ['pmos_4e', 'nmos_4e', 'pmos_4t', 'pmos_4f']
for i in serials:
    find_serial(i)
```

Using `f.read().split()` will give us a list with each word in the text, and since all these serials are one word this is a good opportunity to use this. Then we can use a `for i in contents` and just compare `i` versus our `serial` and increase the `x` count.

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 helpin.py 
> pmos_4e count: 6
> nmos_4e count: 6
> pmos_4t count: 6
> pmos_4f count: 6
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You see only the first value because you hold only one counter and increment it alone.

The best way of achieving your intention is to simply use collections.counter:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('C:/Users/joann/Desktop/pmos.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
count = Counter(content.split())
```

then you can simply do :

```
count['pmos_4e']
```

to get the number you look for

And the final code should look like that:

```
def find_serial(*serials):
     with open('C:/Users/joann/Desktop/pmos.txt', 'r') as f:
         content = f.read()
     count = Counter(content.split())
     for serial in serials:
         print(count[serial])
```

(As you can see there is no need for two loops...)